# Control the VerticalOffset of a webbrowser in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, vertical-scrolling

I am using the webbrowser to show some string with a appbar-button. When I click the button, the webbrowser will NavigateTo another string. Everything goes well except that once the webbrowser is scrolled down(When the user is reading the end of a article), when the button clicked, the webbrowser is still at the bottom, the user has to scroll the webbrowser up.

So, before the new article is loaded, I want to set the verticaloffset of the webbrowser to zero. But there is no scrollviewer in the webbrowser, so I can't use the ScrollToVerticalOffset method.

would anyone know how to Control the VerticalOffset of a webbrowser?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try invoking a script (javascript) to scroll to top? Does that work? See [`InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402855(v=vs.92).aspx) You'll need to have scripting enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402855%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which allows you to invoke JavaScript within your page. If you add the following JavaScript function:

```
function setVerticalScrollPosition(position) {
  document.body.scrollTop = position;
}
```

Then invoke the following (C#)

```
this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("setVerticalScrollPosition", this.vScrollPos.Text);
```

Your browser control should scroll (courtesy [of this blog post](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/manipulating-web-browser-scroll.html))

Comment: Hi,ColinE, thanks for your tip. But when I call the InvokeScript, it caused a " An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006. "

Comment: @ellic try googling ... http://slodge.blogspot.com/2010/12/error-80020006-on-wp7-invokescript-on.html http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/94832/567369.aspx

Comment: @ellic try setting IsScriptEnabled="True"